# Blank Screen on Wall Post from IPhone WebApp

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I have a iPhone webApp that posts content to a users wall. It works fine from a web-browser Chrome, Safari etc but on the iPhone in WebApp mode the callback is not fired.

I guess I'm missing a parameter or option somewhere. I've tried various combinations of frictionlessRequests and display mode.

```
FB.init({appId: "MY APP ID", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, frictionlessRequests:true}); 

function streamPublish(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: '',
        picture: '',
        name: 'My Demo',
        caption: 'My Picutre',
        display: 'touch',
        description: 'This is my attempt to post to facebook'
    }, function(data) {
        alert('Facebook Callback');
        console.log('Facebook Message Post');
    });                  
}
```

Has anyone managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `api` method on the FB object - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

You are using the deprecated REST api.

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Wasim, I've swapped to the FB.api call within a FB.Login response and I still have the same behaviour. It hangs on a empty grey screen.

Comment: What you should do is use a remote Javascript console - http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html - then you can debug the iPhone browser (using a web based console) and you can check for errors. Once you have an error, it might give you a better idea of what the issue could be.